# Storing and counting unique vowels/consonants

Tags: python-3.x

So the purpose of this program is to ask for strings one word at a time until a user has inputed 'aeiou' or 5 consonants, not counting repeats. It only adds consonants after the last vowel in a string. for example if you entered 'hello' then 'luck' then 'liar' the program would stop asking for inputs and then print 'eouia' for the vowels that were entered in order and '5' and would print 'ckr' and '3' for the consonants. I cant seem to find a way to get the consonants portion to work it wont print anything back. any help is appreciated.

```
    VOWELS = 'aeiou' 

    #stores the amount of vowels and consonants according to the parameters above
    vowcount = 0
    concount = 0

    vowcollected_str = ''
    concollected_str = ''

    last_vowel_index = 0

    #ends the program once 5 vowels or consonants have been stored
    while vowcount < 5 and concount < 5: 
        word = input('Input a word: ')
        wordlow = word.lower()

        for i, ch in enumerate(wordlow):
            if ch in VOWELS:
                last_vowel_index = i
                if ch not in vowcollected_str:
                    vowcollected_str += ch 
                    vowcount += 1
                    if ch not in VOWELS:
                        if wordlow[i+1:] not in concollected_str:
                            concollected_str += (wordlow[i+1:])
                            concount += 1

    print("\n"+"="*12)
    print("{:8s}{:7s} | {:12s}{:7s}".format("vowels","length","consonants","length"))         
    print("{:<8s}{:<7d} | {:<12s}{:<6d}".format(vowcollected_str,vowcount,concollected_str,concount))
```